# How do I parse a tmx file (xml file for translation data) in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-file

I am using TMX files (xml file for translation data) as my source in Logstash to index data in Elasticsearch.

A sample TMX file looks like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tmx version="1.4">
  <header creationtool="ModernMT - modernmt.eu" creationtoolversion="1.0" datatype="plaintext" o-tmf="ModernMT" segtype="sentence" adminlang="en-us" srclang="en-GB"/>
  <body>
    <tu srclang="en-GB" datatype="plaintext" creationdate="20121019T114713Z">
  <tuv xml:lang="en-GB">
    <seg>The purpose of the standard is to establish and define the requirements for the provision of quality services by translation service providers.</seg>
  </tuv>
  <tuv xml:lang="it">
    <seg>L'obiettivo dello standard è stabilire e definire i requisiti affinché i fornitori di servizi di traduzione garantiscano servizi di qualità.</seg>
  </tuv>
</tu>
<tu srclang="en-GB" datatype="plaintext" creationdate="20111223T112746Z">
  <tuv xml:lang="en-GB">
    <seg>With 1,800 experienced and qualified resources translating regularly into over 200 language combinations, you can count on us for high quality professional translation services.</seg>
  </tuv>
  <tuv xml:lang="it">
    <seg>Abbiamo 1.800 professionisti esperti e qualificati che traducono regolarmente in oltre 200 combinazioni linguistiche; perciò, se cercate la qualità, potete contare su di noi.</seg>
  </tuv>
</tu>
<tu srclang="en-GB" datatype="plaintext" creationdate="20111223T112746Z">
  <tuv xml:lang="en-GB">
    <seg>Access our section of useful links</seg>
  </tuv>
  <tuv xml:lang="it">
    <seg>Da qui potrete accedere a una sezione che propone link a siti che possono essere di vostro interesse</seg>
  </tuv>
</tu>
```

What I need to do here is to access each `<tu>` block as an event, where the two `<tuv>` blocks inside will be used as the data fields. The data stored in the first `tuv` block will be indexed in ES as the source language data field and the data stored in the second `tuv` block is the target language data field.

A TMX document can contain more than 10000 `tuv` blocks.

I am having troubles using the xml filter and it looks like this now,

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/en-gb_pt-pt/81384/81384.xml"
            start_position => "beginning"
        codec => multiline {
                pattern => "<tu>" 
                    negate => "true"
                    what => "previous"
        }
    }
}

filter {
    xml {
        source => "message"
            target => "xml_content"
            xpath => [ "//seg", "seg" ] 
    }
}

output {
    stdout {
            #codec => json
            codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Here is a part of my index template,

```
"segment": {
            "_parent": {
                "type": "tm"
            },
            "_routing": {
              "required": "true"
            },
            "properties": {
                "@timestamp": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
                },
                "@version": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "source": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "true",
                    "fields": {
                        "length": { 
                            "type":     "token_count",
                            "analyzer": "standard"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "target": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "true",
                    "fields": {
                        "length": { 
                            "type":     "token_count",
                            "analyzer": "standard"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ì'd suggest a simple approach, using grok or dissect filter.

```
filter {
    dissect {
        mapping => { "message" => "%{}<seg>%{src}</seg>%{}<seg>%{trg}</seg>%{}" }
    }
    mutate {
       remove_field => ["message"]
    }
}
```

And you get:

```
{
          "path" => "/en-gb_pt-pt/81384/81384.xml",
    "@timestamp" => 2017-08-25T15:07:34.567Z,
           "src" => "The purpose of the standard is to establish and define the requirements for the provision of quality services by translation service providers.",
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "my_host",
           "trg" => "L'obiettivo dello standard è stabilire e definire i requisiti affinché i fornitori di servizi di traduzione garantiscano servizi di qualità.",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "multiline"
    ]
}
```